# What is the meaning of the tetragrammaton vowelised to read Elokim?

Tags: ezekiel--the-book, shemos-sacred-names

Related to [Why is the Tetragrammaton vowelized in Siddurim and in Sefarim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/why-is-the-tetragrammaton-vowelized-in-siddurim-and-in-sefarim)

I noticed in [Yechezkel 28 (25)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16126#showrashi=true) that the tetragrammaton is vowelised to read Elokim.

Now I thought that the tetragrammaton signifies the attribute of mercy see and that Elokim signifies the attribute of judgement, see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12338/was-the-world-created-with-din-or-with-rachamim).

What is the meaning then of the tetragrammaton vowelised to read Elokim?

Is it maybe for G-d merciful in judgement?

Comment: Is this not a general _k'ri/k'siv_ question? I.e. "How should we interpret a word which has a different written and pronounced meaning?"

Comment: @WAF I do not feel my question is general. Yechezkel could have written אלקים and chose to write the tetragrammaton vowelised to read Elokim. It is the reason for this specific change that interests me here.

Comment: You want a specific application of the answers to this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14671/3

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Everytime the word אֲדֹנָי comes before the word יְהוִה (in all instances that I have seen), יְהוִה "is vowelised to read Elokim". Why would the massoretes do this? Does ancient Hebrew grammar call for such?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok why at www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16126, in the same passage, Ezekiel 28:25 the word YHWH is vowelized like this,  יֱהֹוִה֒ whereas, the same passage at http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1228.htm it is יְהוִה ?