# How can Hashem make a mistake in thinking to make the world with Elokim (Midas Hadin)

Tags: rashi, shemos-sacred-names, parashat-bereishit, creation

[Genesis 1:1 Rashi s.v. ברא א-להים](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#showrashi=true&v=1):

> ברא א-להים: ולא אמר ברא ה׳, שבתחלה עלה במחשבה לבראתו במדת הדין, ראה שאין העולם מתקיים, הקדים מדת רחמים ושתפה למדת הדין, היינו דכתיב (להלן ב ד) ביום עשות ה׳ א-להים ארץ ושמים׃

I have a few questions from 1:1-2:4 on this point:

1. How can Hakodosh Baruch Hu make a mistake in thinking to make the world with Elokim (Midas Hadin)?
2. How can Hakodosh Baruch Hu make an even a bigger mistake in lasting until 2:4 (see rashi) with the same mistake? Even when, for example, humans make a house, if they see one wall falls down they make the wall with a different, stronger material. So this seems like an even bigger mistake by Hashem for keeping Elokim until 2:4.
3. So you're saying that 1:1-2:14 is just the creation that Hashem made with midas hadin which could not survive?
4. If not then why does it keep saying Elokim from 1:1-2:4 and He only realizes His mistake at 2:14 after creation?

Comment: Why do you think it was a "stimake"?

Comment: Grammar and spelling are not requirements for valid questions, but they are appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://www.shlomokluger.com/Other-Books/Arvei-Nachal/Bereishis.html#1) for a detailed explanation of this concept.

Comment: @user4523 The link is broken; could someone please explain what it means to make a world with "Elokim"

Comment: [Here is an updated link](http://www.shlomokluger.com/translated-books/arvei-nachal/bereishis.html) to the commentary [cited above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41079/how-can-hashem-make-a-mistake-in-thinking-to-make-the-world-with-elokim-midas-h#comment112209_41079).

Answer (score 1):

1. Hakodosh Baruch Hu did not make a mistake. שבתחלה עלה במחשבה means that was the starting point, that is, the ideal. Had a human thought this through, that would have been his starting point.
2. How is midas hadin a mistake? It is not workable on its own, but it is not a mistake.
3. The placement of the verses does not mean "between these verses it is midas hadin". They just happen to be two verses that discuss the midos used.

   If we only had 1:1, we would not know that midas harachamim was used.
   If we only had 2:14 we would not know that midas hadin was better, or that it should come first.
   By having both, we discern what the ideal is and what was actually used.
4. Similar to the above. Only one shem need be used. We learn the connection in 2:14, and that the entire world used both (something that would not be expressed in any verse other than it and 1:1.) Elsewhere, whichever shem is more appropriate is used, though it is not necessarily a negation of the other shem.

Comment: 1. I do not understand this for 1 reason if I am a architect and I went to college for 4 years learning all about etc. and when I make a wall I am going to make the wall strong in the beginning because I know what works and does not so to hashem which is higher than infinite it should not come up on his mind that he should do the wrong thing (not correct)

Comment: 2. according to google this is what mistake means: an action or judgment that is misguided or wrong. Hakosh Barch Hu made an action that is wrong or misguided i.e he did an action (it enter his mind i.e he so to say thought) that it should be created with midas hadin which is wrong and it could not survive so he made it with midas harachamim

Comment: 3. So why does it fix it's "mistake" on 2:14 it could of said only elokim in 1:1 and then 1:3 when is actually creating it is both but that is not so when he is creating he is using midas hadin.

Comment: 4. So if he at the end created it with midas harachamim it should be created with Hashem?

Comment: Midas hadin is the *ideal*. Hashem wanted to create an *ideal* world, which means using midas hadin. However, the world would not survive that way, so he "compromised" and added midas harachamim to it. There is only only one action of creation, and there is no "change". Just *explanation* of the ideal and actuality.

Comment: Tkactch: We see from what you are saying that even though it is ideal it could not survive meaning it is has a flaw which is a mistake. (And if you want to go back to my wall example: If I build a wall but half of the materials I put right but the other half not. That is still called a mistake with the wall)

Comment: Not survive does it mean it has a flaw. It means the ideal is not practical. Indeed, practical things are rarely flawless or ideal. Practical thing are...practical.

Comment: "It means the ideal is **not** practical" Meaning that it is missing something which makes it have a flaw. For example a wall when you make it, if you are going to make it ideal but not practical or not ideal but it is practical then the latter one is the better wall and better person who made the wall and that is the ideal way to do it in the end. Another example: A really smart person never says the ideal he says the practical so how much more so hashem who is smarter than the smartest.

Comment: “A really smart person never says the ideal he says the practical” That is a matter of preference, P/J on the MBTI, which is split about 50/50 amongst the population. Ps like to be practical, Js like being correct. We can discern both our preferences already. :) Long discussions in the comments are discouraged. If you would like, we can discuss this in a chat room, and modify the post here shuld we come to a conclusion we both agree with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15673/discussion-between-boruch-tkatch-and-user613).

Answer (score 0):

When we say that the world wouldn't survive, we point that the **world** is too *weak* for the meaning of the Creation, and God needed to create the world in a lower form so it will develop over time so that it could stand the Midas Hadin. This was done so that the Midas Hadin would be something that the world **lost** and not a new thing to achieve (since regaining what you lost is more motivating than gaining something new); the world was therefore created in the higher form, even though it couldn't stay there, so that it could work to come back to that higher level that it was on to begin with.